# Unwanted untracked files in the snapshot - Git

Tags: git, github, git-clone

I'm a noob.
Here's what I've already done:
made a

```
git init
```

that created a `.git` in my `home` folder.

Now, while following the tutorials, I cloned a repository that I had previously created through my account on [GitHub](http://www.github.com), which had a README and a LICENSE file only.

Now this command:

```
git clone url
```

was executed from my home directory, and a new folder got created in my home folder with the name, XYZproject.

Now, when I do,

```
git status
```

I get a list of **all the files in my home folder** as ***untracked files***. That is, basically. I'm confused and in my opinion, this is not what's supposed to be.

All I was trying to do, was to try to add files in the XYZproject folder, able to modify it, and to watch these changes get reflected in my account on GitHub.

Could anyone help me here with what's wrong?

Comment: try git pull once if these files are getting tracked

Comment: Basically, you made your home directory into a Git repo. :)

Comment: @rave763 What will that do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first step was unnecessary, you shouldn't have done a `git init` in your home folder. You don't need that, you only do that when you want to create a new local repo. Since you cloned the repo from your GitHub account, you didn't need to create a local repo.

Simply delete the `.git` folder from your home folder. The. `cd` into your cloned folder and work from there.